# inserting big random data into blob column

Tags: oracle

I need to debug some flow and to do that, I need to generate at least some 100k rows, using say:

```
insert into a.b(DATA, ID, ORDER_ID) 
SELECT UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('too short!'), 
       raw_to_guid(sys_guid()),
       level 
FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= 5;
```

but that data are too small! I don't care what data is it, it can be all ones. I can generate random bytes base64 encoded, but I have no idea how to pass it into oracle, but it would be even better to fix somehow the code above and generate it on db side. Can someone advice?

Comment: You have dbms_random.string(opt,len) to generate random strings.

Comment: but that returns varchar and SYS.UTL_RAW complains for too long string even for very short ones.

Comment: I don't get the error but it is truncating to first 4000 char so the max is 8000 raw string whatever the Len parameter to random.string(), you can do the job in PL/SQL and concat into a CLOB.
You have also UTL_RAW.concat that will raise the limit to 32K.

Comment: But if you really don't care about the data, you don't need to wrap the random.string() into cast_to_raw().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a function to generate a BLOB from random data; and since Oracle 12c that can be an on-the-fly function defined in a `with` clause ([read more](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/with-clause-enhancements-12cr1)):

```
insert /*+ WITH_PLSQL */ into b (data, id, order_id)
with
  function generate_blob return blob as
    l_blob blob;
  begin
    dbms_lob.createtemporary(l_blob, false);
    for i in 1..50 loop
      dbms_lob.append(
        l_blob,
        to_blob(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(dbms_random.string('p', 2000)))
      );
    end loop;
    return l_blob;
  end generate_blob;
select generate_blob,
       raw_to_guid(sys_guid()),
       level
from dual connect by level <= 5;
```

which inserts five rows with a random 100-byte BLOB value; this query shows the length and the first 20 bytes to show they are random:

```
select order_id, id, lengthb(data), rawtohex(dbms_lob.substr(data, 20, 1)) from b
```

| ORDER_ID | ID | LENGTHB(DATA) | RAWTOHEX(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(DATA,20,1)) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAFAB7EF-11F8-EED5-E053-182BA8C00F30 | 100000 | 773C2F707E7D406D712D575B3C3D3135273F276B |
| 2 | AAFAB7EF-12F8-EED5-E053-182BA8C00F30 | 100000 | 676E282367235D455E2F4F547872315A59705A31 |
| 3 | AAFAB7EF-13F8-EED5-E053-182BA8C00F30 | 100000 | 422D5C503F64733A623C215A49696D4640643B3F |
| 4 | AAFAB7EF-14F8-EED5-E053-182BA8C00F30 | 100000 | 5426716867607C203F6D253A2843666F4E203472 |
| 5 | AAFAB7EF-15F8-EED5-E053-182BA8C00F30 | 100000 | 2E353E5228723356407D566026374E4B5E617447 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IqOJF34f?hide=12)

You can make the BLOBs much bigger if you want, just by change the loop's upper bound from 50 to something larger.